# How to upload a file Using Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

i want to upload a pic using robot framework into this :
[image]

I tried this :

```
Add PJ
    Scroll Element Into View    xpath://div[@class='drop-zone text-center']
    Choose File     xpath://label[@class='label-dropZone']    ..\Resources/Robot-framework-logo.png
```

but i'm getting this error :

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the underlying Selenium function behind `Choose File` does is to enter the text you give to it (that's the path to the local file), in an `<input>` element. These elements are the ones defined in the HTML standards for uploading files.

In "fancier" upload UI these input are hidden - the user doesn't see the file path, but sees explanatory text "choose a file here or drag&drop it", with pleasing formatting. This is the case with your example - and targeting that `<label>`, Selenium has failed by saying it is not interactable - one cannot "type" on it; it does need an `<input>`.

You may/should try to find the `<input>` in the form, though hidden, and target it. Sometimes that is not possible though - there might be JS code preventing you to change it; so the success rate is varying.